# Invalid_argument Array. blit ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I typed a pattern matching case

```
let myfnc fr dr = 
    match something with
    |not important
    |not important 
    | Obj (a,b,c) -> Array.blit rm fr rm dr a; (dr+a,dr)
```

Where `fr` `dr` and `a` are integer values and `rm` is the name of my array

It is compiling but I am getting a runtime error saying invalid argument `Array.blit`.

`rm` is an array of size `64`, `fr` is a location below `31` and `dr` is a location above `32` while `a` is a value below `5`

what can be the problem ?

Comment: Show the length of the array `rm` and the values of `fr`, `dr`, and `a`. But if you just look at these, I suspect the answer will be obvious.

Comment: rm is 64 in size,  fr dr represents locations fr below 31 dr after 32 and a is just a size below 5

Comment: You say dr is after 32. How big could it be? If it's bigger than 59 or so, you could have an invalid target range. I suggest just printing out the values. It really should be obvious what's wrong.

Comment: dr start from 32 actually and it is suppose to be the middle of the array

Comment: Do you have strong evidence of the values of the parameters when you get the exception? Truly I suspect that if you look at the values the problem will be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that either you assumptions doesn't hold, or that `dr + a >= Array.length rm`. It is a good idea to check your assumptions:

```
assert (dr > 32);
assert (fr < 31);
assert (Array.length rm = 64);
assert (a < 5);
assert (dr + a < Array.length rm);
```

Comment: you are right the assertion is failing for dr above 32